# Excel Workbooks - Share Connection File to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, connection

I have multiple Excel 2016 and Excel 365 files, all with different queries and connections, pointing to a SQL database.

The database exists on multiple servers - for testing etc.

I would like to be able to connect the spreadsheets to each of the different servers e.g. TESTA1 PRODA01 without having to update each individual Excel workbook.

Is this possible using Excel and without having to change network settings like DNS.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this situation is pretty much what ODBC data sources were designed for. The data connections in the Excel workbooks reference the ODBC data sources and the ODBC data source define the database connection. Alternatively, you could read your connection attributes from a text file at run time.

Comment: Thank you  for the response i will consider this

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I put together some VBA code to list all connections in Excel and update all these same connections.

```
Public Sub UpdateConnectionStrings()

FromString = Worksheets("AccessLinks").Range("A1").Value
ToString = Worksheets("AccessLinks").Range("A2").Value

i = 1

Dim conn As Variant
Dim connectString As String
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections

        connectString = conn.ODBCConnection.Connection

            Worksheets("AccessLinks").Range("D" & i).Value = connectString

            connectString = Replace(connectString, FromString, ToString)
            connectString = Replace(connectString, FromString, ToString)

            Worksheets("AccessLinks").Range("E" & i).Value = connectString

        conn.ODBCConnection.Connection = connectString
        i = i + 1

        FindPathBegin = InStr(1, conn.ODBCConnection.Connection, "DBQ=") + 4
        FindPathEnd = InStr(1, conn.ODBCConnection.Connection, "Database1.accdb")
        FindFullPath = Mid(conn.ODBCConnection.Connection, FindPathBegin, FindPathEnd - FindPathBegin)


    Next conn

MsgBox ("Done!!")
End Sub


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 


Sub DataExtractFromSQL_Server()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Data Source=SERVER_NAME"

'Now open the connection.
' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset


Worksheets(1).Cells.Clear

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Validation")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

For j = cnt To 1 Step -1

    cnPubs.Open strConn
    Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(j)
    ' conn is the name of the connection string; not the connection string
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE_PREFIX_NAME].[dbo].[" & conn & "]"
    With rsPubs

        .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
        .Open Sql
         For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
             Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1) = conn
             Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 2) = .Fields(i - 1).Name

             Select Case DataType
             Case .Fields(i - 1).Type = "200"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "VARCHAR"
             Case .Fields(i - 1).Type = "131"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "DECIMAL"
             Case .Fields(i - 1).Type = "135"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "DATE"
             Case Else
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "INT"
             End Select

             LastRow = LastRow + 1
         Next i
    End With
    cnPubs.Close

Next j

Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this response I will try it out